# Confused by spring scope request

Tags: spring, scope, aop

My scenario is track info by unique id in Spring mvc application.
firstly, I implemented HandlerInterceptorAdapter

```
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response, Object handler) throws Exception {
     //generate UUId and put into request attribute
     request.setAttribute(USAGE_KEY, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
 }
```

secondly, I implement interceptor to capture the USAGE_KEY by autowired HttpServletRequest

```
@Component
@Scope(value = org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class interceptor implement IInterceptor {
   @Autowired(required = false)
   private HttpServletRequest req;

   public synchronized String getUsageKey() {
       System.out.println("this instance ***" + this);
       System.out.println("this request hash code ***" + req.hashCode);
       System.out.println("this key in request ***" + req.getAttribute(USAGE_KEY));
       return req.getAttribute(USAGE_KEY);
   }
}
```

then other two interceptors extends this parent class, let's take interceptor1 and interceptor2 as example, these two interceptors used to catch different services. but the services will be invoked in one same httpservletrequest.

when running, the output like below

```
 this instance *** interceptor1@6bb749
 this request hash code  *** 28916864 *** 
 this key in request *** deb17c31-246c-46d2-8f1e-96ec16c4a803 
 this instance *** interceptor2@17ff7c0
 this request hash code  *** 23761317*** 
 this key in request *** deb17c31-246c-46d2-8f1e-96ec16c4a803
```

I am confused by this result, the key is the same and I suppose the hashcode of the request in different interceptors should be same, but they are not.
And I only send request once.

Comment: What gets autowired is a proxy to the request. You shouldn't rely on the request's hashCode to know if both variables reference the same logical HTTP request.

Comment: hi JB. so you mean the proxy may modify the hashcode of the object?

Comment: No. What I mean is that what you're printing is, presumably, the hashCode of two different proxies, both referencing the same logical HTTP request.